# how to find if browser support flash players by coldfusion or javascript?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, flash

I want to put one audio player in my website. For that I need to know if user's browser have flash player installed. Otherwise I will use different player to play audio file(.wav).

I will be glad to know its solution by either javascript or coldfusion. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Adobe Flash Player Detection Kit](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/download/detection_kit/). It includes client side detection using javascript.